# How to give a sorting predicate in Core data model editor

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data

I am able to create a fetch request in core data model editor. I can get all the objects from it. But I want to sort them according to name.

I know I can write a fetch request with a predicate and then execute it. But i want it to be done from core data model editor. Any idea how to do it.

I am attaching the fetch request image and the Entity image.

Please tell me how can I add a sorting parameter for attribute "name" for the Entity Themes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that you have to add the sort descriptors in code, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071765/how-to-sort-core-data-fetched-properties.

Comment: @MartinR - This is not what I asked for. See my question first. I know I can do it from code. But how can i give the same in Model Editor. I hope you have understood my question.

Comment: @sudipto.bd: The same link you have shared what Martin R shared.

Comment: @Jassi: I think that I understand your question. But it seems that adding a sort descriptor in the model editor is *not possible,* and that is said in the linked-to Q&A.